# could you please let me know how to write regex for ABC1234 OR abc1234a OR abc1234s in splunk?

Tags: regex

I am writing regex in splunk tool `ABC1234 OR abc1234a OR abc1234s`

for this I have implemented `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+` but which is matching only `abc1234a`,`abc1234s` not `abc1234`

and need to write it for `a` `s` should come after `abc1234` so please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Sure your regex matches `abc1234a`? I would say the correct regexp is `[a-zA-Z]{3,}[0-9]+[as]?(?!(\w))`

I assume that the first part is at least 3 characters, and I use a [negative lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Checkout [this](https://regex101.com/r/oMYmxh/2) for details.

I recommend to read trough https://www.regular-expressions.info/ as well as using https://regex101.com/ to test your expressions

Comment: Thank you it's working and thanks for your suggestion.but the given regex populating the  remaining  accounts as well but my need is to populate if anything abc1234 or after this abc1234a or abc1234a only populate.

which is populating the accounts as well (IUSR_LOUWEBWPL287S01 and LOUAPPWPS2090$)   no special characters should not come.

Comment: Sorry don't fully understand what you mean. It may be good if the answer does not satisfy your question be more precise in waht you want to achieve

Comment: simple I need regex should only populate(abc1234 or abc1234a or abc1234s) but from your regex you mentioned which is populating the would be like (SIMCMFWPG09P201$ or IUSR_LOUWEBWPL287S01) so this type accounts should not come,only populate (abc1234 or abc1234a or abc1234s)

Comment: Do you always have a single letter at the end or can it be various? The more details you can give the easier it is to compose the correct pattern

Comment: yes correct
1)abc1234 OR 
2)abc1234a(only a) OR
3)abc1234s(only s)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[as]?\b
```

[demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/PffLRe/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match exclusively the words **ABC1234**, **abc1234a**, **abc1234s** and nothing else, this is how you do it:

```
ABC1234|abc1234[as]
```

**Explanation**: matches `ABC1234` OR `abc1234` with an extra character in the set {a,s}.

If you want a general regex that matches these words, you can go for

```
[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{4}[as]?
```

**Explanation**: matches 3 letters (lowercase or uppercase), then matches 4 numbers, then, if it exists, match one character in the set {a,s}.